# Can't populate the ArrayList<> in a different class

Tags: java, arraylist, populate

I have to populate my `ArrayList<FictionBook>` in the class `Librarian`, but when I use `fictionBooks.add();` it doesn't recognize the variable `fictionBooks`. This is my current code. Also I'm not sure how to populate it with `add(String, String)`.

```
public class FictionBook {
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private static final int AVAILABLE = 1;
    private static final int ONLOAN = 0;

    public FictionBook(String theAuthor, String theTitle){
        this.author = theAuthor;
        this.title = theTitle;
    }

    public int borrow() {
        System.out.println("The book is already borrowed.");
        return ONLOAN;
    }

    public int returnB() {
        System.out.println("The book was just returned.");
        return AVAILABLE;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

I create the arraylist here:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Library {
    private static final int CAPACITY = 200;
    public ArrayList<FictionBook> fictionBooks = new ArrayList<FictionBook>();

    public Library() {
        //fictionBooks = new ArrayList<FictionBook>();
    }

    public void addBook(FictionBook book) {
        fictionBooks.add(book);
    }

    public void deleteBook(FictionBook book) {
        fictionBooks.remove(book);
    }

    public void borrowBook(FictionBook book) {
    }

    public void returnBook(FictionBook book) {
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(fictionBooks, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    }
}
```

And I need to populate it in here containing ("Author", "Title"):

```
public class Librarian {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fictionBooks.add("Jon", "Tiltle");
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call it through an instance of the class, it's not a static list, so the main method doesn't have it in it's scope

Comment: This smells homework so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fictionBooks` ArrayList **belongs to** your `Library` class. That means that you first need to create an instance of `Library`:

```
Library library = new Library();
```

and then, since your `fictionBooks` variable is a list of `FictionBook`s, you have to first create one before you can add it to the list like so:

```
FictionBook fictionBook = new FictionBook("Jon", "Title");
```

Now you can access your new library's `fictionBooks` variable and add your newly created `fictionBook` to it:

```
library.fictionBooks.add(fictionBook);
```

But since you've already got a method in `Library` called `addBook(FictionBook)`, I would recommend using this instead like so:

```
library.addBook(fictionBook);
```

Those last two steps can be condensed into one line, so the finished code would look like this:

```
public class Librarian {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Library library = new Library();
        //Creating and adding the Fiction Book to the list in a single line of code.
        library.addBook(new FictionBook("Jon", "Title"));
    }
}
```

Loads of correct answers here already, but I just thought I would elaborate a bit further in case it might help you understand the problem better. :)

Comment: Glad to help! If you would like to you can accept this as the answer to your question by clicking the tick icon to the left. But feel free to accept someone else's answer if it was more helpful! When you accept an answer you will get some reputation points and so will the answerer.

Answer (score 3):

`fictionBooks` belong to the `Library` class. You will have to instantiate it first.

```
public class Librarian {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Library library = new Library();
        library.addBook(new FictionBook("Jon", "Tiltle"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I tried sorting the books in an alphabetical order by Author's name but it didn't work out. It gives me the error: The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<FictionBook>, Comparator<String>)

Comment: Please accept the answer as thanks :-) As for the rest of the comment, well, it is another question but in short you have to use a `Comparator<FictionBook>`

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `Library` :

```
    public class Librarian {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Library library = new Library();
    library.fictionBooks.add(new FictionBook("Jon", "Tiltle"));

    }
}
```

Or better yet with the methods of `Library` :

```
    public class Librarian {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Library library = new Library();
    library.addBook(new FictionBook("Jon", "Tiltle"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to expose a method saying getBooks in Library and Librarian would then use Library like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Library library = ....;
    library.getFictionBooks().add(new FictionBook("Jon", "Tiltle"));
}
```

Note aside, You should probably think about relation among library, librarian and say library has librarian and you could compose librarian within library.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a book by using this code in your Librarian classes main-method:

```
    Library library = new Library();
    FictionBook yourBookToAdd =  new FictionBook("Jon", "Tiltle")
    library.addBook(yourBookToAdd );
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: He has initialised the Arraylist in the same line as its declaration. He doesn't need to initialise it twice.

Comment: @Redtama ohhh yeah thats right, I just saw the line in the constructor - thanks I will fix my answer